# How can I upload Images with Preview in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been trying to upload multiple images WITH preview in NextJS (React). I tried changing the constants to arrays and tried mapping through them but it just doesn't seem to work and I don't know how I could get it to work.
I've made a component out of the upload functionality and here is the code that works for uploading a single image with a Preview.

uploadImage.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import styled from "styled-components";

function imageUpload() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const fileInputRef = useRef();
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setPreview(reader.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    } else {
    }
  }, [image]);

  return (
    <div className="flex ">
      <StyledImg
        src={preview}
        style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
        onClick={() => setImage(null)}
      />

      <StyledButton
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          fileInputRef.current.click();
        }}
      />

      <input
        type="file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        accept="image/*"
        ref={fileInputRef}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const file = e.target.files[0];
          if (file && file.type.substr(0, 5) === "image") {
            setImage(file);
          } else {
            setImage(null);
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const StyledButton = styled.button`
 
`;

const StyledImg = styled.img`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
`;

export default imageUpload;
```

Comment: If there are not some resource constraints on your side, you can use some library like this instead of trying to reinvent the wheel: https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-previews

Comment: I just tried it and it works pretty fine however there don't seem to have an option to remove a single image after uploading many or add images one at a time. Do you know a way ?

Comment: Yeah, take a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-buk2rw?file=pages%2Findex.js

Comment: God bless you @brc-dd that's the thing I was looking for when trying to code it myself. No need to reinvent the wheel 

Answer (score 0):

Based on these references https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-previews and https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-buk2rw?file=pages%2Findex.js  I replaced my code with the following

ImageUpload.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import styled from "styled-components";

function DragAndDrop() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: "image/*",
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      setFiles((files) => [
        ...files,
        ...acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
          Object.assign(file, {
            key: file.name + randomId(), // to allow adding files with same name
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
          })
        ),
      ]);
    },
  });

  const removeFile = (file) => {
    setFiles((files) => {
      const newFiles = [...files];
      newFiles.splice(file, 1);
      return newFiles;
    });
  };

  const thumbs = files.map((file, i) => (
    <div style={thumb} key={file.key}>
      <div style={thumbInner}>
        <img src={file.preview} style={img} />
      </div>
      <button type="button" style={removeButton} onClick={() => removeFile(i)}>
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  ));

  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      files.forEach((file) => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
    },
    [files]
  );

  return (
    <section className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <StyledP className="flex align-center justify-center">
          Glisser Images Ici ou Cliquer pour selectionner
        </StyledP>
      </div>
      <aside style={thumbsContainer}>{thumbs}</aside>
    </section>
  );
}

const StyledP = styled.p`
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px;
`;

const randomId = () => (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);

const thumbsContainer = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  marginTop: 16,
};

const thumb = {
  display: "inline-flex",
  borderRadius: 2,
  border: "1px solid #eaeaea",
  marginBottom: 8,
  marginRight: 8,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  padding: 4,
  boxSizing: "border-box",
  position: "relative",
};

const thumbInner = {
  display: "flex",
  minWidth: 0,
  overflow: "hidden",
};

const img = {
  display: "block",
  width: "auto",
  height: "100%",
};

const removeButton = {
  color: "red",
  position: "absolute",
  right: 4,
};

export default DragAndDrop;
```